How to retrieve text of sql queries that were executed in specific transaction
In my production environment, rare undisposed transactions occur that hold lock on one tables. I want to fix it in my application code.
I can get the TransactionId and SessionId ad hoc, but
how do I get SQL Commands executed within the transaction so that I can trace it down to application code?
This is how I get the long living undisposed transaction id:
SELECT trans.session_id AS [SESSION ID] 
    ,login_name AS [Login NAME]
    ,trans.transaction_id AS [TRANSACTION ID]
    ,tas.name AS [TRANSACTION NAME]
    ,tas.transaction_begin_time AS [TRANSACTION BEGIN TIME]

FROM sys.dm_tran_active_transactions tas
JOIN sys.dm_tran_session_transactions trans ON (trans.transaction_id = tas.transaction_id)


By using a framework that does it for you by joining the ambient transaction or creating a new transaction. "A transaction scope can select and manage the ambient transaction automatically." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/transactions/implementing-an-implicit-transaction-using-transaction-scope

Im not sure if we are talking about the same. I know how to execute query in transaction. I need to retrieve the query text from some logs afterwards. I rephrased my question

Fixing the code defect will obviate the need for contingency janitorial services.

I don't know what code is causing it. I'm trying to find out by examining the SQL commands

Since you get the transaction id from the query you shared with us, the following query may help you use DMVs to get the SQL text of those queries related with the transaction:
SELECT 
req.session_id,
req.status,
req.command,
req.cpu_time,
req.total_elapsed_time,
sqltext.TEXT,
req.transaction_id
FROM 
sys.dm_exec_requests req
CROSS APPLY 
sys.dm_exec_sql_text(req.sql_handle) AS sqltext
WHERE 
req.transaction_id = 3797934;

Alternatively, you can use Extended Events to capture all queries on a XEL file and later extract queries that are related to a specific transaction ID.
CREATE EVENT SESSION [CaptureQueryText] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_statement_completed
(
ACTION(sqlserver.sql_text)
WHERE sqlserver.transaction_id = 'your_transaction_id'
)
ADD TARGET package0.event_file
(
SET filename = 'C:\temp\CaptureQueryText.xel'
);

